# What does unnamed parameters must be written with the empty name '_' mean?

Tags: swift, parameters

I'm learning Swift from a book and we are using Playgrounds to build out a class.  I received an error that reads: unnamed parameters must be written with the empty name '_'.

I understand an underscore in Swift means "to ignore" but if I add an underscore followed by a space then I receive the error: Parameter requires an explicit type which is fairly easy to understand, meaning that a parameter must be declared as a certain type. :)

I'd like to know exactly what the error "unnamed parameters must be written with the empty name '_'" is trying to say in layman terms because its not making much sense to a noob like me.

Here is the code from the playground up to this point:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"

func fahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheitValue: Double)-> Double {

    var result: Double

    result = (((fahrenheitValue - 32) * 5) / 9)

    return result
}

var x = fahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheitValue: 15.3)

print(x)





class Door{

    var opened: Bool = false
    var locked: Bool = false
    let width: Int = 32
    let height: Int = 72
    let weight: Int = 10
    let color: String = "Red"

    //behaviors
    func open(_ Void)->String{
        opened = true
        return "C-r-r-e-e-a-k-k-k...the door is open!"
    }

    func close(_ Void)->String{
        opened = false
        return "C-r-r-e-e-a-k-k-k...the door is closed!"
    }

    func lock(_ Void)->String{
        locked = true
        return "C-l-i-c-c-c-k-k...the door is locked!"
    }

    func unlock(_ Void)->String{
        locked = false
        return "C-l-i-c-c-c-k-k...the door is unlocked!"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, your code was something like this, when you get **`unnamed parameters must be written with the empty name '_'`**.

```
func open(Void)->String{
    opened = true
    return "C-r-r-e-e-a-k-k-k...the door is open!"
}
```

Seems you are an experienced C-programmer.

In Swift, single-parameter functions (including methods) should have this sort of header:

```
func functionName(paramLabel paramName: ParamType) -> ResultType
```

When the `paramLabel` and `paramName` are the same, it can be like this:

```
func functionName(paramName: ParamType) -> ResultType
```

You can use `_` both for `paramLabel` and `paramName`, so this is a valid function header in Swift, when a single argument should be passed to the function and it is not used inside the function body:

```
func functionName(_: ParamType) -> ResultType
```

But in old Swift, you could write something like this in the same case:

```
func functionName(ParamType) -> ResultType
```

Which is not a valid function header in the current Swift. So, when Swift compiler find this sort of function header, it generates a diagnostic message like: **`unnamed parameters must be written with the empty name '_'`** which is suggesting you need `_:` before the `ParamType`.

---

The actual fix you need is included in the Lawliet's answer. You have no need to put `Void` inside the parameter when your function takes no parameters.

```
func open()->String{
    opened = true
    return "C-r-r-e-e-a-k-k-k...the door is open!"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Parameter requires an explicit type**. Therefore, the `func open(_ Void)->String` function declaration causes a compile error. If you just want to write a function that has no argument, remove `_ Void`.

```
func open()->String{
    opened = true
    return "C-r-r-e-e-a-k-k-k...the door is open!"
}
```

---

According to Apple's Swift book, the **underscore (_)** can be used in various cases in Swift.

**Function**: If you don't want an argument label for a parameter, `_` can be used rather than having an explicit argument.

```
func sumOf(_ arg1: Int, arg2: Int) -> Int{
    return arg1 + arg2
}
sumOf(1, arg2: 5)
```

**Numeric Literals**: Both Int and Float can contain `_` to get better readability.

```
let oneBillion = 1_000_000_000
let justOverOneThousand = 1_000.000_1
```

**Control Flow**: If you don't need each value from a sequence, you can ignore the values by using an `_`, aka the [Wildcard Pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/wildcard-pattern), in place of a variable name.

```
let base = 2
let power = 10
var result = 1

for _ in 1...power {
    result *= base
}
```

**Tuples**: You can use `_` to ignore parts of a tuple.

```
let http404Error = (404, "Not Found")

// Decompose to get both values
let (statusCode, statusMessage) = http404Error
print("The status code is \(statusCode)")
print("The status message is \(statusMessage)")

// Decompose to get the status code only
let (justTheStatusCode, _) = http404Error
print("The status code is \(justTheStatusCode)")
```

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, this is a practice from objective C that is carried and respected in swift. In objective C style, you name your parameters, but when you don't need them for description or readability purposes, you can just use `_`. Here's an example

```
init(_ parameter: Type)
```

Objective C protocols also follow this naming convention -

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView.......)

// in swift

protocol MyCustomProtocol: AnyObject {
    func controller(_ controller: MyCustomControllerClass, DidFinishLoadingSomething something: Type)
}
```

When you do want to name your parameters in your functions, you can -

```
class CustomClass {
    init(withUserId id: String)
}
// to use the above:
CustomClass(withUserId: "123123")

func insert(newIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath)
... 
insert(newIndexPath: myNewIndexPath) // This is how you would use the above function
```

To help with your problem specifically, you specified that your `func open` does not need a parameter name. But you never specified what your parameter is. If you do want to pass a parameter, call it `func open(_ open: Bool) -> String {` , or if you don't want a parameter for that function, just use `func open() -> String {`